# In acumatica, how can I grab the value of a selector and use it to fill another field?

Tags: c#, acumatica

As seen in the image below, I want to try and pass the value of the Selector to the Attention field. I'm trying to make it so that whenever I choose a new selector value, the Attention field will be updated with the selector's value.

[image: Contact Selection]

The Contact Selector in the image above is a Custom Field, so I was trying to access it through it's extension. However, I couldn't seem to get it working.

Here is the Data Access screen showing how the field is set up:

[image: Data Access screen]

Here is the code so you can grab it if needed:

```
[PXDBString(50)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Contact")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.displayName,
LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>>>))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(
    Where<Current<PMContact.customerID>,
            Like<Contact.bAccountID>>), "")]
```

Below are my two attempts of trying to grab the extension. I've tried using these pieces of code in various events; RowSelected, RowUpdated, FieldUpdated. Nothing seemed to work, which obviously means I'm not grabbing the extension properly, but I'm not sure what else to try.

**Attempt 1**

```
protected void PMContact_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{  
   var row = (PMContact)e.Row;

   if (row == null) return;

   PMContactExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<PMContactExt>();

   if (rowExt != null) {
     row.Attention = rowExt.UsrContactSelect;
   }   
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
protected void PMContact_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
      
   var row = (PMContact)e.Row;

   if (row == null) return;

   PMContact items = (PMContact)Base.ItemSettings.Current;
   var itemExt = PXCache<PMContact>.GetExtension<PMContactExt>(items);
      
   row.Attention = itemExt.UsrContactSelect;  
}
```

This attempt was giving me an error about the ItemSettings part:

> \App_Code\Caches\ProjectEntry.cs(43): error CS1061: 'ProjectEntry' does not contain a definition for 'ItemSettings' and no accessible extension method 'ItemSettings' accepting a first argument of type 'ProjectEntry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm a bit stuck on what else I can try to make this happen.

Do you have any other suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much for your help @Hugues and @Robert!

As Hugues mentioned, my custom field had CommitChanges=False so I changed it to true and voila, it worked!

It worked fine using the RowSelected event, but I took Robert's advice and changed it to FieldUpdated to ensure I'm doing things more suitably.

This is the code I used when the event was triggered:

```
protected void PMContact_UsrContactSelect_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{  
   var row = (PMContact)e.Row;

   if (row == null) return;

   PMContactExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<PMContactExt>();

   if (rowExt != null) {
     row.Attention = rowExt.UsrContactSelect;
   }   
}
```

Thanks so much again! This issue has been a really stubborn one :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Field updated event on your selector field. The row_selected is geared more for driving the behavior of the UI.

https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=9048a6d5-41a0-a5bd-9b78-7ce9833114b2

Comment: Thanks @Robert! I managed to solve it by adding CommitChanges=True to my custom field, and I changed my event to FieldUpdated as you recommended to make sure it was completed in a more suitable manner :D

Comment: Glad you got through the issue and am happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

ItemSettings dataview is in InventoryItemMaint graph, are you extending InventoryItemMaint?

Also it does not contain PMContact DAC, it is selecting InventoryItem DAC.

I would not expect this line of code to work for this reason:

```
   PMContact items = (PMContact)Base.ItemSettings.Current;
```

> I've tried using these pieces of code in various events; RowSelected, RowUpdated, FieldUpdated. Nothing seemed to work, which obviously means I'm not grabbing the extension properly,

I'm not sure about the conclusion here. Did you debug the code to make sure the PMContactExt extension is null?

Did you debug to make sure the events called? If events aren't called you need to add CommitChanges=True property on the ASPX control.

RowUpdated event should be used instead of RowSelected because RowSelected is not recommended to set DAC field values.

Is PMContact DAC  a Projection? If it's a projection you will need to extend both the projection and the base DAC.

**EDIT** it is not a projection:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Hugues. How would I check if a DAC is a projection?

Comment: Search for the class with keyword 'class PMContact' in Acumatica Source Code page. If the DAC class isn't decorated with PXProjection and inherits directly from IBqlTable we can conclude it's not a projection. I edited my answer on that.

Comment: Ahh ok great, thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: Key thing to look at here is where exactly is it stuck in the process. Does it call the event, is any variable unexpectedly null, does the field gets updated in memory, on ui, in database etc..

Comment: And remove unnecessary code that could create unwanted side effect. For example, PXRestrictor could be a reason why the value gets validated out automatically.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Hugues! I just had to add CommitChanges=True and it worked perfectly! :D